# Transpose a dataframe to a nested list of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got situation where I need to transpose a dataframe like below.

input dataframe is as below:

```
input_data = [
    ['Asia', 'China', 'Beijing'],
    ['Asia', 'China', 'Shenzhen'],
    ['America', 'United States', 'New York'],
    ['America', 'Canada', 'Toronto']
]
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
input_df.columns = ['continents', 'countries', 'cities']
input_df
```

|  | continents | countries | cities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Asia | China | Beijing |
| 1 | Asia | China | Shenzhen |
| 2 | America | United States | New York |
| 3 | America | Canada | Toronto |

The output data I want to get is

```
# only the unique values are allowed in the output list.
continents = ['Asia', 'America']
countries = [['China'], ['United States', 'Canada']]
cities = [[['Beijing', 'Shenzhen']], [['New York'], ['Toronto']]]
```

For this case, the input data has three levels Continents -> Countries -> Cities, but what I ultimately want is to take a multiple-level hierarchical dataframe (no matters how deep it is horizontally), then I get the output like the example, and then I will put them on a pyqt5 column view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas.Series.tolist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) can convert series value to list.

```py
print(input_df['continents'].unique().tolist())
print(input_df.groupby('continents', sort=False)['countries'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).tolist())
print(input_df.groupby(['continents', 'countries'], sort=False)['cities'].apply(lambda x: [x.unique().tolist()]).tolist())
```

```
['Asia', 'America']
[['China'], ['United States', 'Canada']]
[[['Beijing', 'Shenzhen']], [['New York']], [['Toronto']]]
```

As for a general approach, the first approach occurred to me is to loop through the columns of `df`.

```py
def list_wrapper(alist, times):
    for _ in range(times):
        alist = [alist]
    return alist

columns_name = input_df.columns.values.tolist()
for i in range(len(columns_name)):
    if i == 0:
        print(input_df[columns_name[i]].unique().tolist())
    else:
        print(input_df.groupby(columns_name[0:i], sort=False)[columns_name[i]].apply(lambda x: list_wrapper(x.unique().tolist(), i-1)).tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks for the try. but only unique values are allowed in the output list. And I want to have a general model to process different dataframes.

Comment: @GazZhao Adding `.unique()` to return only the unique values.

Comment: Thanks. That I know. I meant how to deal with a dataframe with no preset number of columns. i.e. The another input dataframe is like "Continents" -> "Countries" -> "Cities" -> "Street" -> this can go on.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I think I can improvise based on your answer. I will post out my solution when done and accept your answer.

Comment: @GazZhao See my edited answer, but it may not the best.

Comment: thanks again. It is almost what I need. One missing part is the list index are not consistent, i.e. Asia is at position 0 in continent list, ['China'] should be also at position 0 of the countries list.

Comment: @GazZhao To preserve order, specify the `sort` argument of `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the order. I just found out your output is different. the desired third output list is cities = [[['Beijing', 'Shenzhen']], [['New York'], ['Toronto']]], it has three inner levels, yours only have two. Sorry for this fuss. I should have pointed it earlier. @Ynjxsjmh